# popup function in html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am new to HTML coding and JavaScript.

I am preparing a report in HTML displaying popup's and associated messages multiple times.

I came to know that id should be unique.

Can anyone help me with code if there is another way of achieving the requirement

```js
function dFunc() {
  var popup = document.getElementById(id);
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```html
<div onclick='dFunc()'>
  OK
  <span class='popuptext' id='dPopup'>
    Message
  </span>
</div>

<div onclick='dFunc()'>
  OK
  <span class='popuptext' id='LPopup'>
    Something
  </span>
</div>

<div onclick='dFunc()'>
  OK
  <span class='popuptext' id='SPopup'>
    new thing
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Ever tried googling "javascript modal popup"?

Answer (score 0):

```
function dFunc(){ var popup = document.getElementById('dPopup') popup.classList.toggle("visible");}
```

Avoid using *onclick* in the **HTML** Pages..

Have Look at this [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp) and next time try to google stuff before you submit a request.